# Connecting to NordVPN breaks my internet connection

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, browser

I was able to install nordvpn, login and connect to a vpn location.
Afterwards everything was mostly fine, I was able to browse google, and install packages with apt. But then I noticed I wasn't able to access github.com using any browser (Firefox, then tried Brave).

I tried deleting the cache and the cookies and changed some other browser settings and now I am able to open github.com, but I cannot access google.com

This behaviour is completely erratic.

I am using ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11, and on windows I don't have this issue with nordvpn connection.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: I had nothing but problems using the NordVPN software, it was so long ago now I can't remember exactly what the issues were, but you don't actually need their software. I uninstalled the software and configured via network manager and not had any problems since. So perhaps you could try that? Not an answer to your question, but could be an alternative solution. The instructions are here: https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1061938702/How-to-connect-to-NordVPN-using-Linux-Network-Manager.htm

Comment: @codlord thanks for the hint. This indeed seems to work just fine. I am now able to browse any webpage with the VPN setup as you said.